# Making images responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an image slider and when the screen gets to 600 or below I want the images to be 100% of the screen width. I have tried to use width: 100% and max: width: 600px thinking this would make them responsive. But now I realise that that just makes them 600px wide not 100% of the screen with a max width. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var image_width = $(".img_cont").width();
  var image_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var carousel_width = image_width * image_count + image_width;
  var padding = $(".active img").height() /4;
  
  $(".carousel").css("width", carousel_width);
  $(".img_cont").css("paddingTop", padding);
  $(".active").css("paddingTop", 0);
  
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 600){
        var image_width = $(".img_cont").width();
        var image_count = $(".carousel li").length;
        var carousel_width = image_width * image_count;

        $(".carousel").css("width", carousel_width);
        $(".img_cont").css("paddingTop", 0);
        $(".active").css("paddingTop", 0);
      }else if($(window).width() < 1600){
        var image_width = $(".img_cont").width();
        var image_count = $(".carousel li").length;
        var carousel_width = image_width * image_count + image_width;
        var padding = $(".active img").height() /4;

        $(".carousel").css("width", carousel_width);
        $(".img_cont").css("paddingTop", padding);
        $(".active").css("paddingTop", 0);
      }else {
        var image_width = $(".img_cont").width();
        var image_count = $(".carousel li").length;
        var carousel_width = image_width * image_count + image_width;
        var padding = $(".active img").height() /4;

        $(".carousel").css("width", carousel_width);
        $(".img_cont").css("paddingTop", padding);
        $(".active").css("paddingTop", 0);
      }
      });
  });
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
}

.carousel{
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_cont img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  max-height:600px;
}

.active img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
  .img_cont img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .active img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
  .img_cont img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .active img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
  .img_cont img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .active img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  
  img_cont{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  } 
  
  .img_cont img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .active img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: use @media query in css

Comment: @HemaNandagopal - OP is. It's in the CSS panel of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed solve it myself. I changed the 600px media query to this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

  img_cont{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  } 

  .img_cont img{
    width: 100vw;
    /* max-width: 600px; */
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: none;
  }

  .active img{
    width: 100vw;
    /* max-width: 600px; */
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

But I don't understand why when I change 100vw to 100% the image just displays at its original width and not 100% of the screen width. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The difference between using width: 100vw instead of width: 100% is that while 100% will make the element fit all the space available, the viewport width has a specific measure, in this case the width of the available screen, including the document margin.

Comment: Thanks I understand what was going on now

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use @media Rule on CSS? 
For example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Now your style will changes based on screen width. For your case we could write like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    carousel {
        width: 100%
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    carousel {
        <whatever you want>
    }
}
```

You could write common attribute without `@media Rule` and write exclusive attribute like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you basic concept.
I just pulled the code from w3school about slider.
Add the container around the images and set images' size as 100% and make container have particular size.
Once I've seen your question, your original image size is not over 600px(guess that's why you want to make it larger(100%) when window size got smaller than that. I just override the css content set max-width as 530px. when it got smaller than 600px, make it 600px.
Please see the code below. hope it will work!

```
<style>
.w3-display-container
{
    max-width:530px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.w3-display-container
{
    max-width:600px;
}
</style>
```

Main code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<style>
.w3-display-container
{
    max-width:530px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.w3-display-container
{
    max-width:600px;
}
</style>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" style="width:100%">


  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) 
  {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) 
  {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
  {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }

  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```